# MiGS change from MD5 hash to SHA 256

Tags: magento-1.9, php, payment-gateway

I just received communication from my bank that MiGS had a security update and i need to change from from MD5 to SHA 256.

I bought the MiGS extension from Hotextension about a 15 months ago but they dont seem to exist anymore.

Can someone please help me out here...Here are the codes...

Current codes

```
// vpc_SecureHash must come last to exclude itself
    $formFields['vpc_SecureHash'] = $this->getHash($formFields, $storeId);
    return $formFields;
}

/**
 * Get hash
 */
public function getHash($formFields, $storeId = false)
{
    ksort($formFields);
    $md5HashData = $this->getConfigData('secure_secret', $storeId);
    foreach ($formFields as $key => $value) {
        if (strlen($value) > 0) {
            $md5HashData .= $value;
        }
    }
    return strtoupper(md5($md5HashData));
}

/**
 * Return URLs
 */
public function getApiUrl($key, $storeId = null)
{
    return Mage::getUrl(self::API_CONTROLLER_PATH . $key, array(
        '_store' => $storeId,
        '_secure' => true
    ));
}

}
```

Here is what i received from the bank

"How do I change from MD5 to SHA 256?
Get your developer to look at your current code and locate where the MD5 hash is being calculated. They will need to look at the logic below and replace the current MD5 hash calculation with the below SHA256 HMAC calculation.

**Step 1: Create string with transaction data via the merchant application.**
Create a string with field names and values in ascending order using the POST data from PHP_VPC_3Party_Order.html:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
// create the hash input and URL leaving out any fields that have no value
if (strlen($value) > 0) {

?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo($key); ?>" value="<?php echo($value); ?>"/><br>
<?php           
    if ((strlen($value) > 0) && ((substr($key, 0,4)=="vpc_") || (substr($key,0,5) =="user_"))) {
    $hashinput .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Create SHA256 HMAC** 
•   Obtain Secure Hash Secret either from the existing MD5 calculation or from Merchant Administration
•   Calculate SHA256 HMAC using the secret as a key to produce the secure hash
Add the hash to the request string to send to the gateway.

```
}
$hashinput = rtrim($hashinput, "&");
?>      
<!-- attach SecureHash -->
<input type="hidden" name="vpc_SecureHash" value="<?php echo(strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $hashinput, pack('H*',$securesecret)))); ?>"/>
```

I am not exactly a developer so can someone please advise what exactly needs to be done?